# Play 2.1 : Access files on server

Tags: playframework-2.1

Let's suppose I have a folder on my server. I want to be able to access this folder from a URL using Play 2.1.
I really don't know how and I have been searching a lot on the Internet, to no avail.

Here is a folder in which there are files I want to access :
/home/user/myFiles

I'd like that when I type the following URL
localhost:9000/filesOnServer/filename
I download the file named "filename" in the folder myFiles.

This is not what I want to do :

```
GET    /filesOnServer/*file     controllers.Assets.at(path="/anything", file)
```

Indeed, this way I can only access files inside the play application directory.
Moreover, if I were to use dist, then the files are stored in a .jar and we can no longer add files to the application.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using scala or java?

I think you should look for `Play.getFile()` and `SimpleResult()`

Here is a sample of a little Controller method in scala, it might not be the most efficient but it seems to work !

```scala
def getFile() = Action {
    val file = Play.getFile("../../Images/img.png")(Play.current)
    val fileContent = Enumerator.fromFile(file)
    SimpleResult(
       header = ResponseHeader(200, Map(
          CONTENT_LENGTH -> file.length.toString,
          CONTENT_TYPE -> "image/png",
          CONTENT_DISPOSITION -> s"attachment; filename=${file.getName}")),
       body = fileContent)
}
```

Hope it will help you!

Note:  you could also use `new java.io.File(absolutePath)`